Now that Azerbaijan has taken control of Nagorno-Karabakh, why does Pakistan still not recognise Armenia?
According to an Azerbaijani source from 2015, Pakistan refuses to recognise Armenia until Armenia withdraws its troops from "Azerbaijan" (meaning Nagorno-Karabakh / Artsakh).  In September 2023, Azerbaijan conquered Nagorno-Karabakh and there are now no pro-Armenian soldiers and almost no Armenians left in the territory.  Azerbaijan has full operational control of the territory, but Pakistan still has not recognised Armenia.
As of 2024, what reason or reasons remain for Pakistan to not recognise Armenia?

Inertia? Lack of a final settlement? It's not like Armenia wouldn't put the troops back there if it could.

Plus, both countries have little trade or people relations with the other and no superpower has vested interests in those relations. There's no "trigger" for Pakistan to recognize Armenia.

@JamesK: the current gov't of Armenia recognized Az's claim to Karabah. It was one of the big reasons invoked by Putin for not helping them.

@JamesK:
Somewhat obscure facts "The Republic of Artsakh was never recognized by any UN member state, including Armenia." The separatist leader Shahramanyan 'took back' the dissolution of Artakh though, once in exile https://www.barrons.com/news/karabakh-dissolution-not-valid-says-separatist-leader-52082a77 But Pashinian's gov't pretty much lashed out at him, for that. https://www.azatutyun.am/a/32746544.html

@JamesK: the leftover conflict between Am and Az is over some villages an possibly over the Zangezur corridor, although Az somewhat backed off on that, but not completely https://eurasianet.org/azerbaijan-revives-demand-for-corridor-through-armenia

@whoisit Laos also has very little trade with Guatemala, or Cameroon with Albania.

Because of Turkish disapproval.
Turkey and Armenia don't have any diplomatic relations between them because of the Armenian Genocide in 1915, which Turkey continues to deny ever happened.
On the other hand, Turkey is one of Pakistan's closest allies, both politically and militarily (the other one is China).
For example, there is a proverb in Pakistan that "Turkey and Pakistan are two countries but one nation."
Turkey is the second most important defense partner of Pakistan, so much so that Turkey banned arms exports to India.

Good answer and plausible.  For people not so familiar with Turkish-Pakistani relations, this answer could be improved by adding sources.

@gerrit, This answer is common knowledge in the South Asian region.

Possibly another factor is that Armenia is buying weapons from India https://www.etvbharat.com/en/!international/why-india-held-first-ever-defence-consultations-with-armenia-enn24051607527 Albeit not a lot, because they are piss poor.

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever, No, it is not a factor at all.
